# React Antd Design Checkbox.Group default checked not happen?

Tags: reactjs, antd

In Antd Design checkbox.group **defaultcheck** not happen , Below is the link

https://codesandbox.io/s/m41yml491p

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `defaultValue` on the `Checkbox.Group`, like so:

```
<Checkbox.Group style={{ width: '100%' }} onChange={onChange} defaultValue="A">
```

[**See it working here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/62kp9pq92n)